# Getting 'invoke': no matching overload function found

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am very new to C++ and am running into an error that I cannot seem to find. The program is supposed to display the time in 12 and 24 hour formats that update every second with a menu to be able to add time in hours, minutes, and seconds. The issue I am having is that when trying to start a thread for the time I get an "'invoke': no matching overload function found" I can call the function to display without the "std::thread displayTime". I am uploading the whole code because I do not know exactly where the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

//declare classes for 12 hour and 24 hour clocks
class standardTime;
class militaryTime;

//enum for AM and PM for 12 hour clock
enum AMorPM {
    AM, PM
} AMPM;

//class Clock with variables for hour, minute and second
class Clock {

public:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};

//class for 12 hour clock which inherits the public Clock class
class standardTime : public Clock {

public:
    standardTime(int h, int m, int s) {
        hour = h;
        minute = m;
        second = s;
        AMPM = AM;
    }

    //if-else statement to set hours to 0 or add one hour
    void addOneHour() {
        if (hour == 11) {
            hour = 0;
        }
        else {
            hour += 1;
        }
    }

    //if-else statement to set minutes to 0 or add one minute
    void addOneMinute() {
        if (minute == 59) {
            minute = 0;
            addOneHour();
        }
        else {
            minute += 1;
        }
    }

    //if-else statement to set seconds to 0 or add one second
    void addOneSecond() {
        if (second == 59) {
            second = 0;
            addOneMinute();
        }
        else {
            second += 1;
        }
    }

    //set friend function
    friend void showTime(const standardTime&, const militaryTime&);
};

//class for 24 hour clock which inherits the public Clock class
class militaryTime : public Clock {

public:
    militaryTime(int h, int m, int s) {
        hour = h;
        minute = m;
        second = s;
    }

    //if-else statement to set hour to 0 or add one hour
    void addOneHour() {
        if (hour == 23) {
            hour = 0;
        }
        else {
            hour += 1;
        }
    }

    //if-else statement to set minute to 0 or add one minute
    void addOneMinute() {
        if (minute == 59) {
            minute = 0;
            addOneMinute();
        }
        else {
            minute += 1;
        }
    }

    //if-else statement to set second to 0 or add one second
    void addOneSecond() {
        if (second == 59) {
            second = 0;
            addOneSecond();
        }
        else {
            second += 1;
        }
    }

    //set friend function
    friend void showTime(const standardTime&, const militaryTime&);
};

//display clock output for both clocks displaying current time
void showTime(const standardTime&, const militaryTime&) {

    //using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    static bool s_finished = false;

    while (!s_finished) {
        time_t timeNow = time(0);
        tm* sTime = localtime(&timeNow);
        tm* mTime = localtime(&timeNow);
        time(&timeNow);

        cout << "***************************      ***************************" << endl;
        cout << "*      12-Hour Clock      *      *      24-Hour Clock      *" << endl;
        cout << "*      ";

        bool AM = true;

        if (mTime->tm::tm_hour > 12) {
            cout << "0" << mTime->tm::tm_hour - 12 << ":";
            AM = false;
        }
        else if (sTime->tm::tm_hour < 10) {
            cout << "0" << sTime->tm::tm_hour << ":";
        }
        else {
            cout << sTime->tm::tm_hour << ":";
        }

        if (sTime->tm::tm_min < 10) {
            cout << "0" << sTime->tm::tm_min << ":";
        }
        else {
            cout << sTime->tm::tm_min << ":";
        }

        if (sTime->tm::tm_sec < 10) {
            cout << "0" << sTime->tm::tm_sec;
        }
        else {
            cout << sTime->tm::tm_sec;
        }

        if (AM) {
            cout << " AM";
        }
        else {
            cout << " PM";
        }

        cout << "        *      *      ";

        if (mTime->tm::tm_hour < 10) {
            cout << "0" << mTime->tm::tm_hour << ":";
        }
        else {
            cout << mTime->tm::tm_hour << ":";
        }

        if (mTime->tm::tm_min < 10) {
            cout << "0" << mTime->tm::tm_min << ":";
        }
        else {
            cout << mTime->tm::tm_min << ":";
        }

        if (mTime->tm::tm_sec < 10) {
            cout << "0" << mTime->tm::tm_sec;
        }
        else {
            cout << mTime->tm::tm_sec;
        }

        cout << "           *" << endl;
        cout << "***************************      ***************************" << endl;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

        
    }

    return;
}

void menu() {

    standardTime time12Hour{ 11, 59, 59 };
    militaryTime time24Hour(23, 59, 59);
    //Show menu
    while (true) {
        cout << "***************************" << endl;
        cout << "*    1 - Add One Hour     *" << endl;
        cout << "*    2 - Add One Minute   *" << endl;
        cout << "*    3 - Add One Second   *" << endl;
        cout << "*    4 - Exit Program     *" << endl;
        cout << "***************************" << endl;

        int userInput;

        cout << "Please enter selection, press 4 to exit: ";
        cin >> userInput;

        //switch statement to translate user input in to correct function
        switch (userInput) {
        case 1:
            time12Hour.addOneHour();
            time24Hour.addOneHour();
            //showTime(time12Hour, time24Hour);
            continue;

        case 2:
            time12Hour.addOneMinute();
            time24Hour.addOneMinute();
            //showTime(time12Hour, time24Hour);
            continue;

        case 3:
            time12Hour.addOneSecond();
            time24Hour.addOneSecond();
            //showTime(time12Hour, time24Hour);
            continue;

        case 4:
            cout << "Goodbye";
            exit(1);
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid selection" << endl;
            break;
        }

        return ;
    }

}

int main() {

    standardTime time12Hour{ 11, 59, 59 };
    militaryTime time24Hour(23, 59, 59);

    //showTime(time12Hour, time24Hour); //this rins withoug issues

    std::thread displayTime(showTime); // this gives code C2672 on line 55 and C2893 on line 51
    displayTime.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`showTime` takes arguments.  Just like you have to specify those arguments when you call it directly, you also have to specify the arguments when you start it as a thread.

Try

```
std::thread displayTime(showTime, time12Hour, time24Hour);
```